# change filesize of iPhoto image before adding it to a mail

Tags: mail.app, photos.app

How can I change the filesize (resolution and compression) of an image from iPhoto before adding it as an embedded image in apple mail without actually changing the image in iPhoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me on Lion (but didn't for a while on Snow Leopard)

When attaching a photo from the Media Browser - you can change things in the lower right corner of the mail message.

[image]

A similar dialog is drawn when you "share" from iPhoto to mail before it hands off the pictures and creates a blank mail message.

[image]

Since the latest iPhoto can "mail" the images directly - might you be using that feature instead? If so - look in the bottom right when composing and you can change the setting before sending (as well as choose from the many templates above the size setting menu.)

[image] [image]

I think there was a bug where running the ready-for-Lion version of iPhoto on Snow Leopard skipped this dialog - but I don't have that setup to test at the moment. Perhaps I just missed the new location of the pop up when mailing them from iPhoto directly.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this was broken at the time of the asking and answering.  I don't see an iPhoto update in the mean time so I'm guessing I and the OP were equally blinded or it was a true bug in the code not showing the settings on Snow Leopard and iPhoto '11. Thanks for the down votes to draw my attention back to this once Lion was released.

Answer (score 2):

If you click the email button in either Aperture or iPhoto, or for any photo you drag into Mail, you'll find a drop-down at the bottom of the window once you select an image that allows you to change the size of the image, and it tells you the size of the resulting file.

Small, Medium, Large, and Original are the options.

As I said, this works for any image in Mail. It won't affect the originals in any way. It's the easiest way I've found to change the images, and it tells you the results on the fly, so you can adjust each image as required.

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto 11 has exactly the same options if you email via Mail, a choice you make in the iPhoto Preferences

Answer (score 0):

You should not be concerned. iPhoto never changes anything about an original image in its library. Originals are always kept in their unedited state. When you crop or scale something, and you export it, such as when you make an email attachment, iPhoto generates a new image in the smaller size, while keeping the original untouched. This also applies to any other kinds of edits, such as changing the exposure, rotating, applying effects, or anything else. You can view an edited photo, and you can export an edited photo or print it, but the iPhoto database always keeps the original photo, and you can always revert to that if you need to.

This concept is called **non-destructive editing**, and it is a feature of many programs that edit images, video or audio--not just the iPhoto program.